# Using Todays Datetime to calculate the completion of a project in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I want to have a DataFrame where I have a start date and end date and then use todays date
to calculate the completion time in %.

DataFrame:

```
   start-date    end-date   
0  01-02-2019  01-07-2022
1  03-07-2020  04-05-2022
```

now I want to add the column "Completion %" which uses the current date to give me the completion time in %

Result DataFrame:

```
   start-date    end-date   completion % (using 14-06-2021)  
0  01-02-2019  01-07-2022    69%          [(today-date)-(start-date)/(end-date)-(start-date)]
1  03-07-2020  04-05-2022    69%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['start-date']=pd.to_datetime(df['start-date'])
df['end-date']=pd.to_datetime(df['end-date'])
```

try:

```
df['completion %']=((pd.Timestamp('today')-df['start-date'])/(df['end-date']-df['start-date'])*100).astype(int).astype(str)+'%'
```

output of `df`:

```
    start-date  end-date    completion %
0   2019-01-02  2022-01-07  81%
1   2020-03-07  2022-04-05  61%
```

Comment: @HaiProgramming If it is what you are looking for then try considering accepting this answer to indicate others that the issue is resolved(click on the tick to make it green)....Thnx ***:)***

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with simple arithmetic.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=[0,1], dayfirst=True)

df['completed %'] =round((datetime.today() - df['start-date'])/(df['end-date'] - df['start-date'])*100,2)

print(df)

""" Sample Output
  start-date   end-date  completed %
0 2019-02-01 2022-07-01        69.39
1 2020-07-03 2022-05-04        51.72
"""
```